# Sitecore: tracking of the last visited page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

On the site that I'm developing we need to track the last visited page for each user (users login to the site). What's the best way to do this? We are already using a custom profile so adding a new field is easy. The site will not have a lot of traffic so updating this field wont be an issue, i think. Are there better ideas? Does sitecore already offers something that we can possible use?

Answer (score 0):

OMS has a "Top Exit Pages" report by default... but that is tracked across sessions, not users.

A good IIS log parser should also be able to give you this information... again, that would be by session (or IP) and not logged in user.

If you really want to get every exit page AND filter by logged in user... what I would do is add a new pipeline processor to httpRequestBegin, and place it after the ItemResolver.  Then save the Item.Paths.Path.  I would advise against writing this data to the user Profile if you are using the default ASP.NET Profile handler and you have a decent amount of traffic, because it is highly inefficient.  Roll your own simple storage solution here, or just dump the data to a log.

Answer (score 0):

My first question would be:  Why do you need only the last visited page of the user?  What are you trying to determine?

In a lot of cases, you are probably starting down an analytics route, or perhaps even trying to drive some marketing.

If the analytics is what you are going for, you can probably just pop an event out to your google analytics account with the current username as an event variable to allow you to look at analytics by user and by page.  Alternatively, you could use the Sitecore OMS/DMS features for tracking all that data and looking at the analytics there.

If you are looking at driving marketing, you probably want to use OMS/DMS, especially if you want to start getting into personalization or engagement plans.  OMS/DMS will track user activity, and all the pages they visit, though not by user account.  With some customizations, you can probably add that data in, but it will depend on what you are trying to use the information for.  The username may not be what is important to you.

If, however, you just want to know what page to send the user back to after logging them in, it would be better to just store that in session or pass as a post parameter if session is not a viable option for you.